# git add subdirectory content to commit

Tags: git, vim

I have my git repo for my vim stuff [MyVim](https://github.com/flebber/MyVim) here it includes my .vimrc and my .vim folder which includes the bundles folder.

I have .git located in my home directory as thats where .vimrc is.
I have committed and pushed to my github, the vimrc the .vim folder and the bundle folders are added. however the folders within bundle are not added and when cloned they are there by name but empty.

I am tryin to add them. Trying various add methods such as.

```
git add '.vim/bundle/*.*'
```

But the commit command always says no changes added to commit.

```
git commit -m 'update submodules'
```

How does this work?

Edit: Commands used creating repo

```
git init
git add .vimrc
git add .vim
git commit -m 'first commit'
git push origin
```

I haven't tried to specifically use submodules or any feature. I only wanted to add .vimrc and the directory .vim and subfolders and their contents. I used the comment 'submodules' above as when googling that was in the answers I was reviewing. However my question seemed simpler than the problems and solutions being offered.

Comment: Any patterns in your .gitignore file that would get in the way?

Comment: Are you using submodules for the bundles?

Comment: Unsure re submodules ammedned above with explanation

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Git doesn't handle files beginning with a dot specially. At least `git add dir/` also adds `dir/.hiddenfile`.

However as you say the folders are created empty when cloning there *must* be some files in there because Git does not manage folders and cannot list empty folders. The only way to create empty folders—at least to my knowledge—is to create a folder with a `.gitignore` file which ignores itself. But I suppose you didn't try to fiddle with this kind of stuff.

So please inspect the directory in question a little better. If unsure please post a `ls -a dir/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git add '.vim/bundle/*.*'
```

does not add folders from the bundle directory because they don't have a dot in its name.
Use

```
git add '.vim/bundle/*'
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

It seems the folders in your '.vim/bundle/' are added as submodules.

Here is my suggestions rather than a direct answer (though I think "git add -A" will do.):

1, If you want to manage you dotVim file with "vim-pathogen+git submodule" read [this](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/#comment-86512237) video or the [README](https://github.com/ying17zi/dotVim) file in my dotVim (I've noted all necessary git commands to setup, update, and clone it elsewhere.).

2, I notice you have vbundle in your '.vim/bundle/'. To manage your dotVim with it, just follow the documentation of vbundle (or refer to [this blog post](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/sane-vim-plugin-management/)).